# Javascript - Clear search output when submitting another text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For my project I need to create a simple search engine for my webpage. 
I need a way to clear my previous search results when I submit another search into the form without refreshing the entire page.

My Javascript file contains the objects I am searching for.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="term" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <button id="search-button" class="btn btn-default" type="button">
        Search</button>
</form>
<div id="results-area"></div>
```

Comment: And your javascript code is?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) It would be nice to edit your question and add the javascript code you've written so far : [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i'm wrong:

Code with jQuery:

```
$(form).submit(function(e){
  $("#results-area").html("");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery it would go like this:

```
$("#search-button").click(function(){
// your search function here
$("#term).val('');
});
```